# unserialize function implementation in php

Tags: php, serialization, deserialization

Recently I was asked to write my own implementation of PHP serialize(), unserialize() functions. My functions should return identical results as original PHP internal functions. 
I made some progress with serialize() function :

```
<?php
    function serializator($input)
    {
        $args = count(func_get_args());
        if ( $args > 1) { throw new Exception("Serializator function requires exactly 1 parameter. {$args} given"); };
        switch ($input) :
            case is_array($input) :
                $length = count($input);
                $str = gettype($input)[0] . ':' . $length . ':{';
                foreach ($input as $key => $value):
                    if (is_array($value)) {
                        $str .= gettype($key)[0] . ':' ;
                        $str .= !is_int($key) ? strlen($key) . ':' . '"' . $key . '"' . ';' : $key . ';';
                        $str .= serializator($value);
                    }
                    else {
                        $str .= gettype($key)[0] . ':' ;
                        $str .= !is_int($key) ? strlen($key) . ':' . '"' . $key . '"' . ';' : $key . ';';
                        $str .= gettype($value)[0] . ':' ;
                        $str .= !is_int($value) ?  strlen($value) . ':' . '"' . $value . '"' . ";" : $value . ';';
                    }
                endforeach;
                $str .= '}';
                break;
            case is_object( $input ) :
                $str = ucfirst(gettype($input)[0]) . ':' . strlen(get_class($input)) . ':' . '"' . get_class($input) . '"';
                $str .= substr(serializator((array)$input), 1);
                break;
            case is_int( $input) || is_bool($input) || is_null($input) :
                $str = gettype($input)[0] . ':' . $input;
                break;
            case is_string( $input) :
                $str = gettype($input)[0] . ':' . strlen($input). ':' . '"' . $input . '"';
                break;
            case is_float($input) :
                $precision = ini_get('serialize_precision');
                $str = gettype($input)[0] . ':' . $input;
                break;
            case is_resource($input):
                $str = 'i:0'; // resource is not serializable
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        endswitch;

        return $str;
    }
```

But struggling with unserialize() implementation. Could anyone point out from where to start thinking or looking? :) Thanks.